# Node.js experience a 30000 time-out occasionally on random routes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

Heroku is my platform
Node.js.  4.8.4

I have a middle layer that takes request and performs logic usually making a query to mongodb

A various times during the day it will start to experience timeout symptoms where I see a 200 respond code but a response time of 30000.  There is not one single route that does this it varies from the simplest query to complex   Without any error and the random routes and suggestions on how to trouble shoot

Comment: How large is your database? Do you have any indexes built? If so, are you certain that they're sufficient and actually being used? How long do your requests typically take to complete? This sounds like an issue with natural variability in query response times combined with a lack of indexing on large collections of documents, but I can't say for certain without knowing anything else.

Comment: It could also be a problem with poorly-structured queries, where your database is responding well and has a good overall structure, but you're e.g. performing many `findOne()` queries in large loops and incurring a lot of additional network overhead.

Comment: Thanks for response.  So when everything is good. All requests are under 300ms.  As I sit here and watch the heroku console.  For every 100 line items. I will see one come thru red for a h12 timeout.  No consistency in route or logic.

Comment: I watched the error in heroku logs....took the same query with headers...ran 50 times back to back in postman...no problem...average 89 ms